# Swipe to switch focused accessibility element iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-storyboard, uiaccessibility

When the user has Voice Over on in certain apps, a one handed swipe to the right or the left changes the focused accessibility element and speaks it (for example, the App Store top charts view). I would like to have this in my own app (which uses a storyboard).

I can think of several ways to do this myself with a swipe gesture recognizer and a list of accessibility elements in order, but it seems like there must be a way to do this in the accessibility API. However, my research has turned up nothing.

Is this a built in feature? If so, how can I add it in my storyboard or in code?

Edit:

Per advice from one of the answer I have implemented the UIAccessibility protocol for my view.Here is the code.

```
- (NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount{
  return 4;
}

- (id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
  return [@[self.menuButton, self.firstButton, self.secondButton, self.thirdButton] objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element{
  return [@[self.menuButton, self.firstButton, self.secondButton, self.thirdButton] indexOfObject:element];
}
```

The view I am having this issue with is defined in an interface builder storyboard. As you can no doubt infer from the code, it has 3 buttons as subviews.

Comment: Your question implies that you're new to implementing accessibility on iOS. I'd strongly suggest you begin with the [Accessibility Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html), then return to StackOverflow with specific, code-level questions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the built-in behavior for VoiceOver and can't be changed on a per-app basis.

If you want to modify the order elements are focused, look at the [`UIAccessibilityContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityContainer_Protocol/) protocol for iOS 7 or `accessibilityElements` property of `NSObject` for iOS 8.  If you don't want to implement either of those, you can also simply set `accessibilityElementsHidden` to `YES` for elements you want VoiceOver to ignore.

Comment: Thanks. This actually does work in other views in my app it seems, just not for one specific one (the only one that I wrote, as it happens). I tried your suggestion to implement the UIAcessibilityContainer protocol, and it does definitely get called and return the UIButtons I want it to when I swipe, but there seems to be no effect on Voiceover's focus.

Comment: Can you add some representative code from your view to the question?

Comment: I have edited the question. Unfortunately the view itself is defined in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by adding accessibility labels to the buttons in the storyboard. Because voice over already spoke their label correctly, I had not bothered to do so before.